# Error in Autcomplete TextBox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I need an auto complete textbox. I tried the following code segment:

```
<input type="text" id="tbx_srchByFn"  class="autosuggest" disabled="disabled" value="fieldname" runat="server"
                                   onclick="this.value=''" />
```

jquery

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "DDL_Home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('tbx_srchByFn').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

.cs file

```
    using System.Web.Services;
    [WebMethod]

    public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("constr"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Name from Register where Name LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
                }
                return result;
            }
        }       


    }
```

when I type on text box i didn't get the output.but when I remove **runat="server"** it works. I just need that in server so that I can take the textbox value from serverside

Comment: insert html textbox value as code behind                                                                      string name = Request.Form["Name"];

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-value-of-HTML-Input-TextBox-in-ASPNet-code-behind-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Add runat="server" and check my solution

Answer (score 0):

> when I remove runat="server" it works.

I think postback happening in your code. so you must rebind `SearchText()` function. Add the following `javascript` in your code.

Try this code :

```
var prm_lp = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
//Re-bind for callbacks
prm_lp.add_endRequest(function () {
SearchText();
});
```